# How to get variable from flask and store to Javascript without rendering template?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have some code from app.py :

```html
   @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
  def fetchtest():
    appsUrl = request.form.get("appsUrl")
    appsData = extractAppsDatafromUrl(appsUrl)
    return render_template('index.html',appsData=appsData);
```

But i want to get variable called appsData from Flask and then store in Javascript variable.
this is my .html :

```html
<script
      defer
      src="{{url_for('static',filename='assets/js/script.js')}}"
    ></script>
    
    
<main class="main">
    
      <form class="form" action="/" method="post">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke="currentColor"
            class="icon"
          >
            <path
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              d="M21 21l-5.197-5.197m0 0A7.5 7.5 0 105.196 5.196a7.5 7.5 0 0010.607 10.607z"
            />
          </svg>

          <input
            name="appsUrl"
            class="input"
            type="text"
            required
          />
          <button class="btn"></button>
        </form>
        
        <div>{{appsData}}</div>
        
 </main>
```

and this is my script.js :

```js
"use strict";

const formats = [];
```

I really consufed how to store from appsData to formats in javascript : (formats = appsData).

and also, when input the URL, it render the template index.html. i won't to do that.
kindly help me please.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to re-render your template after receiving the POST request, but want to send data from your endpoint to javascript, you should consider sending the request using AJAX. You can then send the data from the variable `appsData` as JSON and assign it to a javascript variable.

To achieve this you need to change your endpoint as follows.

```py
from flask import jsonify

@app.post('/')
def fetchtest():
    appsUrl = request.form.get('appsURL')
    appsData = extractAppsDatafromUrl(appsUrl)
    return jsonify(data=appsData)
```

On the client side, register a listener for the form's submit event, suppress the form's default behavior, and submit the entered data using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). The data obtained is then parsed and assigned to a variable and can be used.

```js
(function() {
    const formElem = document.querySelector('form');
    formElem.addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = await fetch('/', {
            method: 'post', 
            body: new FormData(this)
        }).then(resp => resp.ok && resp.json());

        const formats = data.data || [];
        // Do whatever you want with the data.
    })
})();
```

Comment: I already try it in script tag before end of <body> in html with this :

 <body>
<script> (function () {
  const formElem = document.querySelector(".form");
  formElem.addEventListener("submit", async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = await fetch("/", {
      method: "post",
      body: new FormData(this),
    }).then((resp) => resp.ok && resp.json());

    const formats = data.data || [];
    console.log(formats);
  });
})();</>
<body/> 

and it works!

Comment: however, when i tried to put in the <head> with <script defer> which contain javascript code, it wont running. my html only running javascript code if i put :

<script
      defer
      src="{{url_for('static',filename='assets/js/script.js')}}"
    ></script>